# Wireless Transmission using NRF24l01 or NRF24l01+ using arduino

Tags: arduino, spi, radio-transmission

I have 8 bit of audio parallel data from PORTD of arduino uno which is to be transmitted using NRF24l01 module based on SPI interface. I just wanted to know how can i achieve SPI for the given situation. Audio ADC(sampling rate 38.5khz) is already done by arduino and generating 1 sample that is of 8bit in 26us and also DAC has been done by using resistor ladder circuit.I thought to convert 8 bit parallel data into serial using IC and then transfer those serial bits using module. Please provide suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you haven't even tried reading any documentation on SPI. You can feed whatever data you want into the SPI, the SPI module is responsible for the serialization of the data.

Try reading the information in [this link](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/16348/how-do-you-use-spi-on-an-arduino).

What you basically need to do is simply copy the samples you read from the ADC to the SPI, accomodating for the communication protocol required by the NRF24l01 on the SPI.